# Why ajax not able to call my struts action class?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have tried to access struts action class using Ajax and show the list generated by action class on JSP but the result is always comes in **error section**. Can any body help me out. And is there any way to debug the JSP pages like java in eclipse?

```
  function loadJson() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "JsonTest1.action",

        success : function(data) {

            var html = "<ol>";
            $.each(data.list, function() {
                html += "<li>" + this + "</li>";
            });
            html += "</ol>";
            $("#jid").html(html);
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert("No values found..!!");
        }
    });
}
```

my action class

```
  public String execute() throws Exception {

    return "SUCCESS";
}

public String getMyList() {
    setList(new ArrayList<String>());
    getList().add("A");
    getList().add("B");
    getList().add("C");
    getList().add("D");

    return "success";
}
```

and here is my struts.xml

```
 <action name="JsonTest1" class="web.MyAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="JsonTest1" class="web.MyAction" method="getMyList">
        <result name="success" type="json"></result>
    </action>
```

Comment: How did you map url paths to actions?

Comment: I have added my struts.xml

Comment: please a add it with `<package>` tag

Comment: You have same action name for both actions. Use `<s:url>` tag to construct action url in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

without your full `struts.xml` I can only suggest you this:
**If you don't want to refresh page: and Just wnt to get List**

```
<struts>
    <package name="pkgName" extends="json-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="JsonTest1" method="getMyList" class="web.MyAction" >
            <result type="json">
                // <param name="root">yourList</param> 
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution of my question . struts-json-plugin jar was not attached in my project. I have seen a reference here..

[How to call Action class using Ajax in Struts 2](http://www.websparrow.org/tutorials/struts/how-to-call-action-class-using-ajax-in-struts2)